# Django error,TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello

Tags: python, django-templates

[this is the structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hRcH.jpg)

```
urls.py------

    enter code here

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import search,view
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^search-form$', search.search_form),
    url(r'^search$', search.search),
    url(r'^test$',search.test),
    url(r'^hello$',view.hello)
]

setting.py------
ROOT_URLCONF = 'HelloWorld.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+"/templates",], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

------the error------

TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello
hello.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
Django Version: 1.7.11
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
hello.html
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 136
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/xStraybird/HelloWorld',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 14 Apr 2017 13:23:10 +0000



i tried many ways in templates's dirs,such as
```

'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+"/templates",], 
'DIRS': '/Users/xStraybird/HelloWorld/templates',
but it doesn't work...django version is 1.7.11
i can't sure that is path error...any help?thanks a lot....

Comment: create variable named `TEMPLATE_PATH` in settings.py i.e `TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` and the write `DIR: [TEMPLATE_PATH,],`

Comment: still wrong.......TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: see my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

```
   TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")], 
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Here we make use of the `os.path.join()` to mash together the `BASE_DIR` variable and `'templates'`, which would for example yield `<workspace>/HelloWorld/templates/`.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the question ...error occurs in setting.py--installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'TestModel',
    'HelloWorld',     #  add  #
]
```

because when we use `render` ,django will find templates in apps which is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`